# settings assetic filter in windows/IIS symfony2 for coffee script

Tags: windows, node.js, symfony, iis, coffeescript

I've got an error on temporary assetics directory when compiling **coffee-script** files.

On linux all works greatly, in MS Windows no.

The error is relative to the path of the default temp directory that is wrong, beacuse the default temp directory is under `[User]\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Node command `os.tmpdir()` return the right path to temp dir, but when using the coffee filter on symfony2 the temp dir point to c:\windows\temp... returning the error invalid directory

symfony2 settings are:

```
    coffee:
      bin: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/.bin/coffee
```

how can i fixed this filter on a windows SO? 
Can I use the `--output` parameters of coffee for examples and compile in another temp directory?

I've already tried to grant full access to `IUSR` in the `C:\Windows\Temp directory`.

thx in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem related to PHP ini file.

the parameter is `sys_temp_dir`

And from the official documentation ([link](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)) it's available since ver 5.5.0 so apparently it's not resolveble.